# How to find the intersection between cuboid and tetrahedron efficiently

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal

I need an efficient approach to finding the intersection of a cuboid and a tetrahedron.

I am new to CGAL but got some basic experience in using it. Currently, I am following [a post](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Intersection-of-two-CONVEX-3D-polyhedrons-td4564202.html) and using the suggested intersection operation `N1 * N2`, where `N1`,`N2` are [Nef polyhedrons](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Nef_3/index.html). But it is not efficient and in fact VERY slow.

Anyone can help with an even more efficient usage of CGAL or the similar library to do this.
If any possibility, a simple tutorial example would be mostly appreciated.

Thank you very much and I appreciate your any hint.

Rong

Comment: Maybe you already know it, but I find this library very useful because it has documentation too - http://www.geometrictools.com/index.html

Comment: Have a look at [Olivier's](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Intersection-of-two-CONVEX-3D-polyhedrons-td4564202.html#a4564543) response in the same post where he describes an alternate(more efficient) approach.